# Awstats not showing visitors

Tags: awstats

I installed awstats recently using these commands:

```
yum install awstats
cd /usr/share/awstats/tools/
/usr/bin/perl awstats_configure.pl
    -> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    -> www.ysend.com
    -> /etc/awstats
/usr/share/awstats/tools/awstats_updateall.pl now
mkdir /home/cron
nano /home/cron/www.ysend.com.cron
    -> 10 * 1 * * /usr/share/awstats/tools/awstats_updateall.pl now
crontab /home/cron/www.ysend.com.cron
crontab -l
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/awstats.conf
    -> Allow from **MY IP**
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

However, when I visit my Awstats page, it only displays 1 unique visitor.  I've had hundreds of unique visitors.  Any idea about what's going on?

If I try to run awstats_updateall.pl, it says:

> From data in log file "/var/log/httpd/access_log"...

How can I tell it to point to /home/ysend/custom.log?

Comment: Here is my virtual host setup:


<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.ysend.com
        ServerAlias ysend.com
        ServerAdmin john@kurlak.com
        DocumentRoot /home/ysend/public_html
        CustomLog /home/ysend/custom.log common
        ErrorLog /home/ysend/error.log
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I set up awstats, but I'm pretty sure there's a directive in the CONF file that you point to your log location.  Be warned if a custom CONF file uses an included main CONF file (like I set up for my servers) because the option could be set in an included file.